# Create a new calculate DateTime field from two other fields, conditional on the presence of text

Tags: pandas, function, datetime, for-loop

I have a Pandas dataframe that contain two DateTime columns, one with 'Start_Date', and another with 'End_Date'.

I'd like to calculate a new 'Mid_Date' field (the average between 'Start_Date' and 'End_Date' for each entry in the dataframe), but for some rows, 'END_DATE' contains 'NULL' (as a text string). For these rows with 'NULL', I need to only use the 'START_DATE' for the new 'Mid_Date' row.

I can't figure out how to do this as a function/For Loop combination. I'd be grateful for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need a loop in your script to achieve this. Let's create an example `DataFrame`. Replace any 'NULL' string in the date columns with `NaN`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Date': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-20'],
                   'End_Date': ['2020-01-06', 'NULL', '2020-01-25']}).replace('NULL', np.nan)

# df
#    Start_Date    End_Date
# 0  2020-01-02  2020-01-06
# 1  2020-01-09         NaN
# 2  2020-01-20  2020-01-25
```

Now parse all date strings to `datetime` objects, then calculate the 'Mid_Date' column by using the start date plus half of the delta in days. Note that now you have 'Mid_Date' as a DateTime column, not only Date. Also, an uneven division by 2 adds some hours to the result:

```
df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']] = df[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['Mid_Date'] = (df.Start_Date + (df.End_Date - df.Start_Date) / 2)

# df
#   Start_Date   End_Date            Mid_Date
# 0 2020-01-02 2020-01-06 2020-01-04 00:00:00
# 1 2020-01-09        NaT                 NaT
# 2 2020-01-20 2020-01-25 2020-01-22 12:00:00
```

You can now replace any 'NaN' in the 'Mid_Date' column with the value from the 'Start_Date' column and if you want 'Mid_Date' to be a pure Date column (strip the H:M:S), you can do that as well by adding `.dt.date`:

```
df['Mid_Date'] = df.Mid_Date.fillna(df.Start_Date).dt.date

# df
#   Start_Date   End_Date    Mid_Date
# 0 2020-01-02 2020-01-06  2020-01-04
# 1 2020-01-09        NaT  2020-01-09
# 2 2020-01-20 2020-01-25  2020-01-22
```

Comment: Look at me, over-complicating things. Thank you!